# TFS get user by name

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to add a test run by the TFS API from excel.
In one of the field in the excel I got the user who executed  the tests.
I want to update it in the server in order to update it I need to get the user as `TeamFoundationIdentity`

```
ims = _tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
TeamFoundationIdentity UserID = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName,  
  userName, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of Visual Studio and TFS are you using?
I'm using TFS2010 and VS2010 and the following code worked fine for me:

```
IIdentityManagementService ims = (IIdentityManagementService)_tfs.GetService(typeof(IIdentityManagementService));
TeamFoundationIdentity UserID = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName,"Mike" , MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
```

Not sure if the problem is just the initialistation of `IIdentityManagementService`, you could give it a try. I suspect that `_tfs` is a valid representation of a `TfsTeamProjectCollection`

Comment: I know this is an old post.  What namespace can I find IIdentityManagementService and TeamFoundationIdentity in?  Is there an SDK that I need?

Comment: I couldn't the tool where I used it, probably not existing anymore. I searched the net and this should be correct:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.server.core.teamfoundationidentity.aspx