# How to get user AccountName for WorkItem from TeamFoundation?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am getting WorkItems from TFS using this code:

```
private static List<WorkItem> GetTfsWorkItems(string projectName)
{
    Uri URI = new Uri("...", UriKind.Absolute);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(URI);
    WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(tpc);
    string query = $@"SELECT *
                      FROM WorkItems
                      WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '{projectName}'";
    return store.Query(query).Cast<WorkItem>().ToList();
}
```

WorkItem have fields "CreatedBy" and "ChangedBy" both of which are strings with user's DisplayName.
I am looking for way to get user's AccountName (or Sid) instead of it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able straightforward to get the AccountName. Fields with username values like the *CreatedBy/ChangedBy* field are stored in the TFS database as a reference to an identity, not simply as the display name.

However querying the list of accounts by display name is not supported. As a workaround you have to dig into the account list and match the display name to an identity. That identity has your AccountName.

With help of `TeamFoundationIdentity`, you could get what you need. Take a look at below tutorials with more details:

- [TFS get user by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502829/tfs-get-user-by-name)
- [Retrieving an identity from Team Foundation Server using only the
  display name](http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8389748/retrieving-an-identity-from-team-foundation-server-using-only-the-display-name/)
- [Get TFS User List (Mail, Sid, Account, Domain)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/14/tfs-api-part-4-get-tfs-user-list-mail-sid-account-domain/) (including the concept of all Identitys in TFS )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Querying the list of accounts by display name is not supported because it's unsafe: there can be two users with the same DisplayName. I took advantage of your recommendations, but I'm still looking for a direct link between WorkItem's fields and TeamFoundationIdentities.

Comment: @I.Dukhin Which you want  just not part of the TFS design for now. You could also dig in the TFS database for it which may do the trick.Take a look at this tutorial-- [How to query Work Items using SQL on the Relational Warehouse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse/). You could also add a [uservocie](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.